# View in IE10 when data is fetched from db got distorted

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, .net-4.0

I have one project in which on button click event from web page some data is fetched from db,
Before clicking on button webpage looks like given below.

http://imgur.com/wUo8Yxg&SXJ5DJO

After clicking on Apply web page looks like this.

http://imgur.com/wUo8Yxg&SXJ5DJO#1

After data is fetched.. it looks fine.

While fetching data query box moved above tabs on left side. and this happens only in IE10. It works fine with chrome and IE8. I have .net 4.0 framework installed.

Can anyone help me with this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some relevant ASPX/HTML markup for the page as well as relevant code.

Comment: I don't have code with me right now.I will update soon But same thing works completely fine with google chrome without moving anything and in IE8 also it works fine. Is there any problem with IE10? or any hotfix is available?

Comment: The problem with IE10 is that it adheres more strictly to standards. You can try to make it emulate IE8 by adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">` to page `<head>`